# Displaying file size in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: gratis, windows-7, visual-studio

Is there a Visual Studio 2013 extension that

- displays the size of the current file in bytes and/or characters (best would be both)
- updates while typing, not only when saving
- is gratis (free of cost)

Not much more to say, it's so simple that I wonder why I can't find it in the gallery.

Why do I need it?

- I want to participate in [code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), where the file size matters
- Because Visual Studio displays line numbers only

Comment: Can you code golf your own extension? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Mawg: oh, if it would only be the FileInfo.Length property... First I need the Visual Studio SDK, become familiar with it, implement the extension, display the value somewhere and finally, FileInfo.Length would only help if the file is saved. Remember that I also want it during live typing. Then I need to package it into a vsix file, sign it and distribute it. All in all, that's probably 2 days of work. But I've already started...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm a bit impatient waiting for an answer. I checked out how difficult it is to implement such an extension and I'm proud to provide you the [Code Golf File Size Extension](http://development.wellisolutions.de/visual-studio-file-size-extension/) for Visual Studio 2013.

Notice the green number on the bottom right of the text editor.

[image: Screenshot of the extension in action]

Why it is an answer:

- Is a Visual Studio 2013 extension
- Works on Windows 7 SP1 x64
- Displays the number of printable characters, accurately measured using `StringInfo.LengthInTextElements()` and not `string.Length`. It does not display the length in bytes, because I was unable to determine the encoding at the moment.
- Updates while typing
- Free, published under MIT license

Full disclaimer: I'm the author of the tool.